# Experiences with escape analysis enabled on the JVM

Tags: java, scala, jvm, escape-analysis

I've just tried the `-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis` option enabled on a **jdk6-u18** VM (on solaris) and had a rather disappointing experience. I'm running a scala application which has rather a lot of actors (20,000 of them). This is a recipe for garbage-creation!

Typically the app can run with 256Mb of heap but generates **huge** amounts of garbage. In its *steady state* it:

- spends 10% of time in GC
- generates >150Mb of garbage in <30s which then gets GC'd

I thought that escape analysis might help so I enabled the option and re-ran the app. I found that the app became increasingly unable to clear away the garbage it had collected until it seemed eventually to spend the *entire time* doing GC and the app was "flatlining" at its full allocation.

At this point I should say that the app did not throw a `OutOfMemoryError` which I would have expected. Perhaps `JConsole` (which I was using to perform the analysis) does not properly display GC stats with this option on (I'm not convinced)?

I then removed the option and restarted and the app became "normal" again! Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1** Did the escape analysis show up as being enabled in JConsole?  You need make sure you're running the VM with the -server option.  I assume you had this working, but I just thought I'd check.

**2** I don't think escape analysis will help the situation with Scala Actors. You might see a big gain if you do something like:

```
def act():Unit = {
   val omgHugeObject = new OMGHugeObject();
   omgHugeObject.doSomethingCrazy();
 }
```

In the example above the EscapeAnalysis would make it so `omgHugeObject` could be allocated on the stack instead of the heap and thus not create garbage. I don't think it is likely that the escape analysis will help with actors. Their references will always "escape" to the actor subsystem.

**3**
Are you on the most recent release of Scala?  There was a memory leak that I believe was fixed in a recent version.  This even caused [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) to spawn off its own Actor library that you might look into.

**4** You might try the G1Garbage collector You can enable it with:

`-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC`

Comment: If it's objects being transferred from one thread to another, not only is stack allocation going to be impossible I guess there will also be problems with Thread Local Allocation Buffers (TLAB). I believe the JRockit JVM is even more aggressive with its thread-local memory behaviour.

Comment: I'm not expecting the escape analysis to be able to help with the actors *per se*, but there are plenty of other implicit conversions going on in the app on the stack which could be elided. I was just hoping to make some kind of dent in the GC overhead!

Comment: The trouble with G1 is that it's impossible using JConsole to actually see what is going on

Comment: Yes - heap analysis was enabled. I don't need `-server` because I'm running on a solaris monster so the JVM is a server one by default. Yes, I'm using scala 2.7.7.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because I now think that something else is going on; I'll ask a separate question

Comment: Escape analysis has been disabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179830/experiences-with-escape-analysis-enabled-on-the-jvm/2183956#2183956

Comment: Try jdk6u21.  Escape analysis has been reenabled

Answer (score 6):

from the [jdk-u18 release notes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u18.html):

> Note that Escape analysis-based optimization (-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis) is disabled in 6u18. This option will be restored in a future Java SE 6 update.

Comment: Yes, it's enabled by default in Java 6u23 and later (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try to increase the new generation size, e.g. `-XX:NewSize=96M XX:NewRatio=3`. Use JVisualVM (included in the JDK), with the [Visual GC](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/plugins.html) Plugin to watch how the young and old spaces are utilised.

Comment: Yes - I tried this and it made hardly any difference whatsoever. I tried ratios ranging from 1 to 4