# Type-safe primitives in Scala

Tags: scala

I'd like to have type-safe "subclasses" of primitives in my Scala code without the performance penalty of boxing (for a very low-latency application). For example, something like this:

```
class Timestamp extends Long
class ProductId extends Long

def process(timestamp: Timestamp, productId: ProductId) {
  ...
}

val timestamp = 1: Timestamp // should not box
val productId = 1: ProductId // should not box

process(timestamp, productId) // should compile
process(productId, timestamp) // should NOT compile
```

There was a [thread on the Scala User mailing list last year](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/typedef-like-like-syntax-for-strong-typing-keys-td1956375.html) which seemed to conclude it wasn't possible without boxing, but I wonder if this is possible now in Scala 2.8.

Comment: `type Timestamp = Long`? Granted it's not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing could be ensured by a plugin. The unsupported and not-working units plugin for Scala, after all, did something like it when it prevented distances to be added to durations.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use type aliases instead? I appreciate that they are not perfect (i.e. they do not solve your compilation issue), but they can make your code clearer without taking the performance hit?

```
type Timestamp = Long
type ProductId = Long
```

Then you can write methods which use the *pimp my library* pattern and let the JVM use escape analysis to remove the runtime overhead:

```
class RichTimestamp(self: Timestamp) {
  //whatever you want here
}
```

Note that all the usual caveats apply: unless you are extremely sure (because you are doing ultra-low-latency programming e.g.), the performance hit of using the boxed type is probably not a concern. I deal with systems processing tens of millions of inputs a day with no issues whatsoever!

Comment: @Jesper With an alias, Timestamp is just *an alias* for Long. This works both ways and Long is thus the *actual type*. So: No. But it does "add intent".

Comment: Ok, but the original poster asked for a type-safe solution - aliases are not a type-safe solution.

Comment: Indeed, this does _not_ introduce any type safety (only a rather useless "coder wishful intent"). Both types would be accepted where one is required, no type safety between the aliases arises from this alone.

Answer (score 2):

The root of the Scala type hierarchy is `Any` with children `AnyVal` and `Anyref`.  All of the integral types (like `Long` in your example) descend from `AnyVal` and you can't create subclasses in that side of the tree.  Children of `AnyVal` represent low level types within the JVM.  Type-erasure means that at runtime there really is no `AnyVal` anymore and if you could make `Timestamp` it would also be lost at runtime.  You need boxing/unboxing as a place to store your wrapper type information.

```
case class Timestamp(ts: Long)
```

A good JVM can eliminate a lot of the boxing/unboxing overhead at runtime.  For example, see [Experiences with escape analysis enabled on the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179830/experiences-with-escape-analysis-enabled-on-the-jvm)

Comment: I don't think escape analysis can help in my actual applications, since these primitives are stored as fields and as map keys. I see how at runtime everything is lost, but is there any theoretical reason the compiler couldn't guarantee type safety at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

This is *now* possible, as of 2.10, with [value classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html):

```scala
object ValueClasses {
  case class Timestamp(timestamp: Long) extends AnyVal
  case class ProductId(productId: Long) extends AnyVal

  def process(timestamp: Timestamp, productId: ProductId): Unit =
    println(s"$timestamp $productId")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val timestamp = Timestamp(1) // should not box
    val productId = ProductId(1) // should not box

    process(timestamp, productId) // should compile
//  process(productId, timestamp) // should NOT compile
  }
}
```

The commented line produces:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : ValueClasses.ProductId
 required: ValueClasses.Timestamp
  process(productId, timestamp) // should NOT compile
```

I don't have an easy way to convince you that the boxing won't happen, since a simple example like this could have boxing optimized away by the compiler, but here's the byte code:

```
  public void process(long, long);
…

  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: lconst_1
       1: lstore_2
       2: lconst_1
       3: lstore        4
       5: aload_0
       6: lload_2
       7: lload         4
       9: invokevirtual #65                 // Method process:(JJ)V
      12: return
```

Comment: Would you care to expand this a little bit? Perhaps an example, or explanation, or a quote from the article you link to?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of primitives ([on the JVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)) is that they are predefined and final, you cannot add further primitives to the JVM, only classes (java.lang.Object in Java or scala.AnyRef in Scala)...

The boxing/ unboxing of a wrapper, as proposed by Ben, `case class Timestamp(ts: Long)`, shouldn't create a substantial performance penality.

Type aliases, `type Timestamp = Long`, are really *aliases*, so there is no way for the compiler to distinguish two aliases to the same type (`Long`).